# Is there a way to sort 'Available roles' in Chef 'Run List'?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

When I login to the Chef Web UI, I am able to edit the run list of a particular node and add roles to the run list.
However, 'Available Roles' on the top left corner is not sorted.

Is there a way to sort 'Available Roles' by name on the top left corner??

Comment: No, there is no way to change the sort order of this list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about the Chef Server 11 web interface because Chef Manage (the web interface for Chef Server 12) does not have the same GUI-based run list editor because I hated that code and wanted to burn it to the ground. The Chef Server 11 web interface (`chef-webui`) is deprecated and no longer supported. It is a security risk to be running it, and you should disable it in all likelihood.

To answer your specific question, no there is nothing in that UI that is configurable to any real degree.

Comment: I tried to do `chef-client -version` and get `Chef: 12.4.1` as an output  Does it mean that i am running Chef server 12 and not Chef Server 11?

Comment: No, the version of Chef Client and Chef Server are unrelated. Run `chef-server-ctl --version` to see the version of the server I think.

Comment: I am getting an error `-bash: chef-server-ctl: command not found`

Comment: How about you paste a screenshot of the UI you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your version of the chef-client, I'm assuming you are referring to the Chef manage interface, if that is case, you can arrange the 'Available roles' section just dragging and dropping them around, exactly the same as you are doing with the 'Run List' section.

Comment: Did that get added back? If so I might have to go stab someone. That draggable JS UI was so bad :-(